# How to sort by NSDate in a custom array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array like this one by "dateRanges", that is a NSDate object.

```
- [0]
  - name : "BREAKFAST"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-18 08:00:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-19 19:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 2
    - [1] : 2
- [1]
  - name : "LUNCH"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-16 08:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 8
- [2]
  - name : "DINNER"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-17 06:30:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-30 16:00:00 +0000
    - [2]
      - [0] : 2015-06-12 17:00:00 +0000
    - [3]
      - [0] : 2015-06-29 09:30:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 1
    - [1] : 2
    - [2] : 3
    - [3] : 3
```

What I do is to call to:

```
extension NSDate: Comparable { }

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
   return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

result.sortInPlace({ $0.dateRanges[0][0].compare($1.dateRanges[0][0]) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```

but the output gets like this:

```
- [0]
  - name : "LUNCH"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-16 08:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 8
- [1]
  - name : "DINNER"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-17 06:30:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-30 16:00:00 +0000
    - [2]
      - [0] : 2015-06-12 17:00:00 +0000
    - [3]
      - [0] : 2015-06-29 09:30:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 1
    - [1] : 2
    - [2] : 3
    - [3] : 3
- [2]
  - name : "BREAKFAST"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-18 08:00:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-19 19:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 2
    - [1] : 2
```

As you can see, it only sorts by the dateRanges[0][0] indexes, (obviously because I'm asking it in the sortInPlace method), but I would like to know how to sort this array by dateRanges regardless of the indexes.
The expected result should be:

```
- [0]
  - name : "LUNCH"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-16 08:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 8
- [1]
  - name : "DINNER"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-12 17:00:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-17 06:30:00 +0000
    - [2]
      - [0] : 2015-06-29 09:30:00 +0000
    - [3]
      - [0] : 2015-06-30 16:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 1
    - [1] : 2
    - [2] : 3
    - [3] : 3
- [2]
  - name : "BREAKFAST"
  - dateRanges
    - [0]
      - [0] : 2015-06-18 08:00:00 +0000
    - [1]
      - [0] : 2015-06-19 19:00:00 +0000
  - hours
    - [0] : 2
    - [1] : 2
```

Comment: can you provide the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @s1ddok I've updated the question with the expected result :)

Comment: oh, i see now. What you need to do is to sort every dateRanges individually and only then proceed to sorting the whole array by [0][0] indexes

Answer (score 0):

As i looked closely at your desired result it seems like it is not sorted in any way and you still get sorted by 0 indexes. So if this are really your goals all you need to do is:

```
MyArray.sortByZeroIndices() //here you use your code
for item in MyArray {
  item.dateRanges.sort(<) // sort every internal array
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in the call:   item.dateRanges.sort(<) I can't do it like that because It has to conform to the Equatable. So then I have to call to item.sortInPlace({ $0.dateRanges[0][0].compare($1.dateRanges[0][0]) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }) but I don't know exactly what I have to put inside the [][]